# see contents of StringBuffer or char[] from a Java heap dump

Tags: java, heap-memory, visualvm, heap-dump, jvisualvm

I have a Java heap dump that I'm analyzing, looking for high consumers of memory. More than 50% of the memory in the dump is in use by two StringBuffers, each of which holds a char[] which (naturally) accounts for most of the memory in the respective StringBuffer. However, when I inspect the char[] in the instance viewer the contents are elided, I think because the strings are so large. I've also tried using `.toString()` in VisualVM's OQL, but that apparently only works on String objects.

Is there any way to figure out what the contents of those arrays is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to write the contents of the internal char arrays of all the `StringBuffer` instances to disk using the following OQL:

```
map(heap.objects('java.lang.StringBuffer'),
 function(it, index) {
  var writer = new java.io.FileWriter("c:/temp/oql/stringbuffer_0x" + it.id.toString(16) + ".txt");
  var chars = it.value;
  for (var i=0; i<chars.length; i++) {
   writer.write(chars[i]);
  }
  writer.close();
})
```